Profiler setting is missing from Application Insights in Azure
I'm trying to do Code Optimizations in Azure for my dotnet 8 web app in azure, according to the documentation I have to enable the Profiler for that app and I'm following instructions from here, but in my web app Application Insights settings there is no option for enabling the profiler:


By any chance have you created your App in Linux Environment? I see there is no option for Linux App Service.

@Harshitha Oh yes, my app is on Linux. Thanks

If you want to continue with Linux App Service itself.Need to check the profiler option in that.Will find and let you know

Will post an answer in detail.

The option to enable Profiler is available only in App Service with operation system Windows.

I have created a sample Web App with Linux Environment.

You can see, there is no option available related to Profiler.



App Service with Windows Environment:


If you want to continue with the Azure Linux App service, you can configure it in the code itself.

Refer this MSDoc which explains the same.
OR

You can find the direct option in Application Insights => Performance.



Thanks, went through the provided docs and now it's showing the data needed.
